# Reload DataTables without page refresh

Tags: datatables

I am using Datatables but I load the data using loop. Not loading from Ajax. Is there a way to update table content without page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

DataTables can consume data using the

```
columns.data
```

and

```
columns.render
```

read the manual for more details https://datatables.net/manual/data/

Answer (score -1):

What you *probably* want is [`rows().invalidate()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows%28%29.invalidate%28%29) which can update all the data for a table like this:

```js
table
    .rows()
    .invalidate()
    .draw();
```

That said, you may only need to update some cells or rows. If you are dealing with a loop you might consider simply updating the rows inside of your loop like:

```js
table.rows().every(function () {     
    this.data('some new row data');   
});
// redraw the table after loop is complete
table.draw();
```

It would be easier to give a more concise answer if you provide more detail in your question - like a code sample, your data source, what is getting updated and when.

Comment: Here is the code I use to populate the table: https://pastebin.com/3XdFZb2K To add new item I use iframe modals and I want after closing this modal or just pressing one button table to get refreshed (and if possible to stay on the same page) with the new info without refreshing the page.